# MySQL Order of Index Checks

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running MySQL And I have a simple table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_schema`.`test1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `unique2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique1_UNIQUE` (`unique1` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique2_UNIQUE` (`unique2` ASC));
```

I then add a row like such:

```
INSERT INTO `new_schema`.`test1` (`unique1`, `unique2`) VALUES ('x', 'x');
```

I then add another row with the same values in the unique unique columns:

```
INSERT INTO `new_schema`.`test1` (`unique1`, `unique2`) VALUES ('x', 'x');
```

I will then get this error as expected:

```
11:54:06    INSERT INTO `new_schema`.`test1` (`unique1`, `unique2`) VALUES ('x', 'x')   Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'unique1_UNIQUE'  0.203 sec
```

My question is, how do I change the order in which MySQL checks the unique values I entered. So, given my example above, I provided two violations of the unique entries (unique1 and unique2), but I want it to check unique2 first, so the error would be like this:

```
11:54:06    INSERT INTO `new_schema`.`test1` (`unique1`, `unique2`) VALUES ('x', 'x')   Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'unique2_UNIQUE'  0.203 sec
```

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I don't think MySQL has any guaranteed order of evaluation for index checks.  However, I would guess that in practice they are checked in creation order.

Comment: If you want to display a message identifying the exact error then there are three conditions to report: 1) 'unique1' failed, 2) 'unique2' failed and 3) both failed.

Answer (score 1):

have you trie change the position like that

```
    UNIQUE KEY INDEX `unique_UNIQUE` (`unique2`,`unique1`)
```

Like that:

```
 CREATE TABLE `new_schema`.`test1` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `unique1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
   `unique2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY INDEX `unique_UNIQUE` (`unique2`,`unique1`)
 );
```

Comment: He has two separate indexes.

Comment: i know , i just told him to make it in one with unique2 first

Comment: But this does not make sense? Two separate unique indexes restrict the enterable data pretty differently than one merged unique index...?!

Comment: Thanks, I did try this however on the table I am trying to execute it on, it seems to change the order of the indexes regardless of the order of them in the query. It does work if I create a new table. Would be better if there was some other solution, but judging by the fact I can't find anything about this documented, I think it's unlikely.